# Property of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be a universe set of living objects. A subset $M$ is the set of males. Every element in $M$ has the property that it is a male. So I think we can say that $M$ has the property of being male. Also, every element in $M$ has either two or fewer legs. Can having two or fewer legs be called a property of $M$?

After reading the comments, I will consider $M$ to be the set of male humans.
To reformulate the question, let $N$ be the set of living objects with two or fewer legs. it seems $M \subset N$. The question is does $M$ has the properties, males and also have two or fewer legs? one can construct $M$ but the other not. What is the word "property" means and how we differentiate between a property which is "if and only if" and another property which is "if"?

After Further understanding the answers, I would like to reformulate the question as follows:
Let $U$ be a set and $M,N$ be subsets of $U$ such that $M \subset N \subset U$. A **property** (at least how I define it) is a mapping $p:D \mapsto \{TRUE, FALSE\}$ where $D$ is a set. The image of $p$ partition its domain $D$ in the standard way into a partition of two parts, one is the set of elements which is mapped to TRUE and the other part is the set of elements which is mapped to FALSE. We say that the set of elements that are mapped to TRUE, is **constructed** by $p$. 
Let $p_{m},p_{n}$ be the properties which onstruct $M$ and $N$ respevtivliy for the domain $U$.
In my understanding in the sense above, every element of $M$ has both the properties $p_{m}$ and $p_{n}$, but $p_{m}$ construct $M$ and $p_{n}$ does not. In other words, we could define $M=\{ x \in U: p_{m}(x)= TRUE \}$ and  $N=\{ x \in U: p_{n}(x)= TRUE \}$. 
My question is the above the standard way to explain it? Further, now when we use this word property or property which constructs a set we need to be careful of two different kinds of properties, one which constructs and another one which does not? If this is true, is there a different way to differentiate or clarify it when we use the word property?

Comment: The *set* of squares in a plane is not itself a square.

Comment: There are many male animals with more than two legs

Comment: @Henry you are right. I should have been more specific to express what I wanted. I wanted to describe human males. I edited the question.

Comment: A postage stamp is small. A collection of a million postage stamps consists entirely of postage stamps, that is, it consists entirely of small things. Does that mean a collection of a million postage stamps is small?

Comment: I do not believe that you can construct $M$, since ‘constructible’ means that by applying the axioms of ZFC you can show me it’s existence. For example, look at the construction of the empty set, or the natural numbers. If you can’t find that, I can show you.

Comment: @celtschk and coffeemath I could be wrong but I think you are trying to differentiate between a property of the elements of a set and the properties of the set itself?

Comment: @HanyIbrahim: Exactly. A set is a different entity and has different properties than its elements. A concrete set example: $\mathbb N$ is an infinite set, but all of its members are natural numbers, and therefore finite. On the other hand, $\{\mathbb N,\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q\}$ is a finite set (it has only three elements), but all its elements are infinite.

Comment: Ok I understood your point and I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as long as you cannot express what a *male* of even a *living object* is in terms of sets, the set $U$ is not *constructible*, and we can only talk about this colloquially. Now if you say "I think we can say that $M$ has the property of being male", I agree to the extent that we can indeed *define* a property of a subset of $U$ to have the property of being male, but be aware that at this point you are *creating* a game (i.e. set of rules, what mathematics *is*) and not playing *within the existent game of mathematics*. The challenge then is to make sure the rules you are creating are not inconsistent, and see if you can deduce new rules from them.

Comment: Why failing of expressing the male set would affect $U$?

Comment: The only things that exist (in the Universe generated by ZFC) are sets. Hence if you cannot tell me what kinds of sets these ‘males’ you’re talking about are, males do not exist.

Comment: What kind of sets is "living objects"? Do you think this set is well defined?

Comment: Specifically: "Which axioms of ZFC have you invoked and in which order to grant existence to the set 'Living things'"?

Comment: Came across this one by accident. Have you gained some more insight into Set Theory? Additionally, I should have mentioned that ZFC is not the only axiomatic mathematics-generating system around. It is, however, the smallest (the Von Neumann universe). But there are other: VonNeum-Bernays-Gödel, Grothendieck Universes that I believe were of great help in Category Theory.